# How do I change a single variable call to multivariable?

Tags: javascript, variables, scripting

I'm working with a script that calls information from members of certain "member groups" (each defined as a class) to paste into a page.

There are 11 "membergroup" classes and I want the script to call from 5 of them. Right now, I have the script fully functioning, but it only can call for one at a time. I'm not sure how to make it multivariable.

```
   var len = $('.mg3').length;
                $(`.mg3`).each(function (index) {

(the rest of the script that pulls information from users with that class)
```

This is the piece that calls from 1 membergroup at a time, here mg3. I would want it to call from m3, mg4, mg5, mg6, mg7 at the same time. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
   var len = $('.mg3', '.mg4', '.mg5', '.mg6', '.mg7').length;
                $(`.mg3`, `.mg4`, `.mg5`, `.mg6`, `.mg7`).each(function (index) {
```

but it just broke the script completely... I've never worked with multivariables before and am still new to scripting.

Comment: Use a loop or a function with an argument. There is no such thing as a "multivariable" that would magically run the same code with different values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could make a css selector that picked all of the classes, something like `$(".mg3, .mg4, .mg5, (etc)")`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is Jquery syntax. (tell if not)
I think you can select different classes by adding a coma between them :

```js
   var len = $('.mg3,.mg4,.mg5,.mg6,.mg7').length;
   $('.mg3,.mg4,.mg5,.mg6,.mg7').each(function (index) {
```

NB : for the ".each", if it doesn't work, you can try :

```js
$('.mg3,.mg4,.mg5,.mg6,.mg7').toArray().each(...
```

However, this obviously work only if your code is supposed to do the same thing with these elements.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It is, and this worked!! Thank you. Sorry for the terribly wordy question!

Comment: For that last example you can also skip jQuery entirely by doing `document.querySelectorAll('.mg3,.mg4,.mg5,.mg6,.mg7').toArray().each(...`

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery's each, you will want to pass each class separated by a comma within the same string.

Since we don't know what your actual each function includes, here is a basic sample that checks if the `$(this)` in the loop has the class so you can do something different if need be. If you don't need to handle that way, you can ignore it and just reference `$(this)` as the element in the loop.

```js
$(`.mg3,.mg4,.mg5,.mg6,.mg7`).each(function (index) {
  if($(this).hasClass("mg3")){
    console.log("mg3");
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass("mg4")){
    console.log("mg4");
  }
else if($(this).hasClass("mg5")){
    console.log("mg5");
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass("mg6")){
    console.log("mg6");
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass("mg7")){
    console.log("mg7");
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass("mg8")){
    console.log("mg8");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mg3">3</div>
<div class="mg4">4</div>
<div class="mg5">5</div>
<div class="mg6">6</div>
<div class="mg7">7</div>
```